# Bucle for en Python con vs categóricas

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Espero me puedan ayudar: estoy haciendo un ejercicio de regresión logística y tengo la primera aproximación de vs significativas para que el modelo (son aquellas marcadas con `True`) las seleccione manualmente. Pero quiero hacerlo por un bucle. Sin embargo, no sé cómo hacerlo debido a que tengo poco tiempo programando.

Gracias.

```
rfe = RFE(lr, n)
rfe = rfe.fit(bank_data[X], bank_data[Y].values.ravel())

z=zip(bank_data_vars,rfe.support_, rfe.ranking_)
list(z)
```

Este es parte de la salida de z, quiero hacer el bucle para seleccionar a todas aquellas que sean `True`:

```
[('age', False, 38),
 ('duration', False, 37),
 ('campaign', False, 17),
 ('pdays', False, 45),
 ('previous', True, 1),
 ('emp.var.rate', False, 19),
 ('cons.price.idx', False, 24),
 ('cons.conf.idx', False, 22),
 ('euribor3m', True, 1),
 ('nr.employed', False, 34),
 ('y', False, 2),
 ('job_admin.', False, 8),
 ('job_blue-collar', False, 5),
 ('job_entrepreneur', False, 39),
 ('job_housemaid', False, 7),
 ('job_management', True, 1),
 ('job_retired', False, 6),
 ('job_self-employed', False, 23),
 ('job_services', False, 43),
 ('job_student', True, 1),
 ('job_technician', True, 1),
 ('job_unemployed', False, 41)]
```

Esta fue la selección manual que hice de las vs significativas en el modelo y quiero automatizar el proceso.

```
cols = ["previous", "euribor3m", "job_blue-collar", "job_retired", "month_aug", "month_dec", 
        "month_jul", "month_jun", "month_mar", "month_nov", "day_of_week_wed",
              "poutcome_nonexistent"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo desde una lista como:

```
z = [('age', False, 38),
     ('duration', False, 37),
     ('campaign', False, 17),
     ('pdays', False, 45),
     ('previous', True, 1),
     ('emp.var.rate', False, 19),
     ('cons.price.idx', False, 24),
     ('cons.conf.idx', False, 22),
     ('euribor3m', True, 1),
     ('nr.employed', False, 34),
     ('y', False, 2),
     ('job_admin.', False, 8),
     ('job_blue-collar', False, 5),
     ('job_entrepreneur', False, 39),
     ('job_housemaid', False, 7),
     ('job_management', True, 1),
     ('job_retired', False, 6),
     ('job_self-employed', False, 23),
     ('job_services', False, 43),
     ('job_student', True, 1),
     ('job_technician', True, 1),
     ('job_unemployed', False, 41)]
```

### Lista por compresión

- Solo la primera columna, desde la lista:

  ```
  significativas = [var for var, rfe_s, _ in z if rfe_s]
  ```
- Todas las columnas, desde la lista:

  ```
  significativas = [vs for vs in z if vs[1]]
  ```
- Solo la primera columna, sin crear la lista completa previamente:

  ```
  significativas = [var for var, rfe_s in zip(
      bank_data_vars, rfe.support_
      ) if rfe_s]
  ```
- Todas las columnas, sin crear la lista completa previamente:

  ```
  significativas = [(var, rfe_s, rfe_r) for var, rfe_s, rfe_r in zip(
      bank_data_vars, rfe.support_, rfe.ranking_
      ) if rfe_s]
  ```

### Aproximación funcional

En el caso de querer obtener las tres columnas y no solo la primera, una aproximación funcional con `filter` y `operator.itemgetter` es muy simple y también eficiente:

- Todas las columnas, sin crear la lista completa previamente:

  ```
  import operator

  significativas = list(filter(operator.itemgetter(1), z)
  ```
- Todas las columnas, sin crear la lista completa previamente:

  ```
  import operator

  significativas = list(filter(operator.itemgetter(1), zip(
      bank_data_vars, rfe.support_)))
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias , funciono perfectamente. Espero que tengas un buen día.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una lista `[]` compuesta por tuplas `()`, hay distintos tipos de for, en este coso puedes usar un `for in`, lo que hace es tomar cada tupla en este caso y llevarlo a una variable item, luego teniendo esta tupla puedes acceder a su segunda posición `[1]` y si ese valor es `True` vas añadir la primera posición a una lista que antes habías creado, y esto se hará para todos los elementos de tu lista.

```
lista = [('age', False, 38),
 ('previous', True, 1),
 ('emp.var.rate', False, 19),
 ('euribor3m', True, 1),
 ('job_unemployed', False, 41)]
resultado=[]
for item in lista:
    if item[1]==True:
        resultado.append(item[0])
print(resultado)
```

Recuerda que el `if` puede ser solo

```
if item[1]:
```